# dotnet core docker container - Unable to bind to https://localhost:5001 on the IPv6 loopback interface

Tags: docker, .net-core

I created an image for .NET core:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 80 443 5000 5001 5010 5011 7000 22676

#ENTRYPOINT [ "bash"]
CMD ["bash"]
```

I run a container from it
`docker container run -it --publish 5000:8018 --name versie3001 -v //c/tijd/mount:/app michel03`

What goes well is that I see the mounted files.
When I create a new website with `dotnet new razor` and I run it with `dotnet run` it tries to run on port 5000/5001 (default ports) but I get this error:

```
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Unable to bind to https://localhost:5001 on the IPv6 loopback interface: 'Cannot assign requested address'.
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Unable to bind to http://localhost:5000 on the IPv6 loopback interface: 'Cannot assign requested address'.
```

Actually it says warn, but the result is the same, when I go to localhost:8018 I get no result (`ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`)

What am I doing wrong here?

I saw an answer saying I should do this in my containerfile:
`ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "watch", "run", "--no-restore", "--urls", "https://0.0.0.0:5000"]`. It does not give me the error (output is `Now listening on: https://0.0.0.0:5000`), which is good, but it also does not connect from `https://localhost:8018` on my local machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `--publish` option is backwards: it's `-p <hostPort>:<containerPort>`, so for your setup you'd want `--publish 8018:5000`.

Startup issues aside, you do need the option to cause the container to listen on 0.0.0.0 (or ::0, if IPv6 works).  If it binds to localhost it will be unreachable from outside its container, including from other containers and from the host.

Comment: Did you here the boink? That was me falling from my chair. I've been trying for hours, and yet now I found out I've got the ports mixed up. Very big sigh. But thanks very much for pointing it out though!

Comment: To be clear: it does indeed work with the 0.0.0.0 part. Looks very strange to me, and not sure why this is, but it does work!